# How much does it cost (in financial terms) to add a MIPS core to a custom ASIC?

Tags: cpu, mips

I am specifically interested in MIPS74 Kc (@1GHz), but anything equivalent would be a useful reference.

I am ultimately after cost in financial (USD) terms, but mm2 wold be a useful start.

Breakdown into licensing and fabrication costs would be ideal. I am not concerned about any NRE (one time) costs.

Assume 100k - 1Mln units. Also assume pin-count, power budget etc... are not an issue. If required, assume 40nm process.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is overly broad, being very dependant upon which fab you're running in and/or a violation of ARM's NDA for licensing.

Comment: A broad question can be made more specific through iteration, however that will hardly be possible unless you specify what details you are missing. It is also unclear what is in violation of ARM's NDA? All information in this thread is based on citations of ARM's public domain statements. May I also comment that the vote is unhelpful as its off-topic an overly broad. I am happy to re-iterate and improve the question with more specific feedback.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be answered before making a spreadsheet and entering all the required numbers.

You write NRE doesn't concern you but if a set of masks (needed to produce the chip in the first place) costs around 500k - 1M USD (depending on the technology node) it is something to take into account. And how about testing, a testing company will easily charge you 200k USD for only building a production test setup.

An important factor is the amount of chips you can get from one wafer and that is determined by the chip's size which is determined by the technology node you choose.

To get any further you will need to determine the amount of silicon area you need for the chip. For that you need to know how many square mm you need. For that you need to know how many gates you need (roughly).

Comment: Aren't the amount of gates (and consequently the required footprint) given for a known processor type? Sure, not everyone will know the mapping (I certainly don't), but I was hoping someone in here would know.

Comment: As for the one time costs,- I am aware that these can be significant in absolute terms. However in the context of my question these are not of direct concern as I can assume that the long term unit volumes will be large enough to dilute these costs to insignificance.

Comment: The amount of gates: yes. The required chip area: not directly as you need to know what technology you're going to use. A certain technology will have a certain amount of gates per square mm. That will give you an estimate of the required area.

Comment: Sure if you **know** you're going to make millions of chips then I agree that the NRE costs will be insignificant assuming the chip is relatively expensive. But what if your product will not run in the millions. For many high-volume chips the NRE costs can still be a significant part of the price even if the chip is very small and cheap. The low price makes the NRE cost per chip a significant factor. Also testing cost can be significant especially for complex chips which need a long testing time. And test time = money.

Comment: Added process assumption in the original question. Any recurring cost (including unit testing) should be factored in the unit cost.

Comment: I think the total NRE will be in the millions of US Dollars. So if you only make 1 million units, it is still significant. I wouldn't think it would cost you $10 in recurring costs to add a mips core to an asic, although at 1 GHz it is a bit higher performance than the one ASIC I have for comparison (which was multi-core ARM).

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any better answer, I'll try to answer my own question based on findings since I first submitted the question some weeks ago:

- die area requirements for various MIPS architectures is available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MIPS_microarchitectures). The table is incomplete, and the closest information to a
  MIPS32 74K is the MIPS32 24K at 0.83mm^2 (unclear for which process
  geometry). [Another reference](http://www.embeddeddeveloper.com/cores/documents/MIPS_74K_rev1.pdf) indicates 2.5mm^2 (including core
  plus caches) @ 65nm process for MIPS32 74K.
- die cost is estimated [here](http://vlsicad.ucsd.edu/courses/ece260b-w07/slides/ece260b-w07-cost-mfg-pt1-final.pdf) at approx 0.10 USD/mm^2 (for a 200mm wafer)

Based on the above, estimated cost is 0.25 USD + licensing & royalties.

Comment: Licensing and royalties should be the significant cost here.

Comment: That'll be something I'd be also keen to find out, though I realize that information on this regard is likely to be scarce and possibly unreliable as most such transactions are private.

Comment: While this is an ARM reference (rather than MIPS), this article: http://techreport.com/review/25067/an-intro-to-all-things-arm states: 1-10M USD upfont license + 1-2% of selling price in royalties